# OkHttp3 Not Returning Back Response

Tags: android, okhttp

There are a lot of examples for making requests with OkHTTP3, however, I am still unable to make a proper request. As far as I know, my setup is correct.

I keep getting back responses that look like below. I do not know what they mean.

> {"contentLength":238,"contentTypeString":"application/json","source":{"buffer":{"size":0},"closed":false,"source":{"bytesRead":0,"completed":false,"delegate":{"closed":false,"finished":true,"maxByteCount":16777216,"readBuffer":{"head":{"data":[123,34,105,115,85,115,101,114,83,117,98,115,99,114,105,98,101,100,34,58,116,114,117,101,44,34,115,101...]}

The way I am making my requests is that I am passing in a request object, and then I use the RequestBody.create() method to convert my request object into the OkHttp RequestBody object. I started thinking that my request body is wrong so I hardcoded a json string. I am receiving the same results. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to wrap this in asynctask? I did not think this was the case if using enqueue.

```
private static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    public void createPostRequest(Request request, final ResultCallback callback,
                                  String url, HashMap<String, String> header) {
        // create gson object
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        String testRequest = "{\"fName\": \"John\",\"lName\": \"Doe\",\"phoneNumber\": \"5555555\",\"isValidated\": \"false\",\"city\": \"Los Angeles",\"street\": \"Sesame Street\"}";

        // set header
        Headers headers = Headers.of(header);
        // form request body
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, testRequest );
        // form request.
        Request okHttpRequest = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)
                .headers(headers)
                .build();

        // prepares the request to be executed
        client.newCall(okHttpRequest).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                // handle error
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String jsonString = gson.toJson(response.body());
                    // jsonString is gibberish as posted above
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am not receiving any errors in my logs. This is all that comes back from OkHttp

> 2019-06-25 12:46:27.435 23219-23248/com.demo.android.address
>   W/oid.address.dem: Accessing hidden method
>   Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-06-25 12:46:27.698
>   23219-23248/com.demo.android.address W/oid.address.dem: Unable to
>   resolve Lokhttp3/internal/http/RealResponseBody; annotation class 2132
>   2019-06-25 12:46:27.699 23219-23248/com.demo.android.address
>   W/oid.address.dem: Unable to resolve
>   Lokhttp3/internal/http/RealResponseBody; annotation class 2132
>   2019-06-25 12:46:27.702 23219-23248/com.demo.android.address
>   W/oid.address.dem: Unable to resolve Lokhttp3/ResponseBody; annotation
>   class 2132 2019-06-25 12:46:27.703
>   23219-23248/com.demo.android.address W/oid.address.dem: Unable to
>   resolve Lokhttp3/ResponseBody; annotation class 2132 2019-06-25
>   12:46:27.707 23219-23248/com.demo.android.address W/oid.address.dem:
>   Unable to resolve Lokio/Buffer; annotation class 2132 2019-06-25
>   12:46:27.708 23219-23248/com.demo.android.address W/oid.address.dem:
>   Unable to resolve Lokio/Buffer; annotation class 2132

Comment: add logs please

Comment: @BorisRuzanov I posted what I am getting back in my logs.

Comment: I guess the problem might be in request. You made it wrong thats why back cant recognize it. Did you try make request with that body in postman?

Comment: The request content is correct. I checked it with Postman and also have done it with Volley.

Comment: so with volley response comes in success or failure?

Comment: Volley is successful. Works really good. But my project requirements is to use OkHttp3. I believe it has to be my requestBody or I am missing a step.

Comment: Try to put log and get information from received object response.getSomething or exception.getMessage()

Comment: The response is: 
{"contentLength":238,"contentTypeString":"application/json","source":{"buffer":{"size":0},"closed":false,"source":{"bytesRead":0,"completed":false,"delegate":{"closed":false,"finished":true,"maxByteCount":16777216,"readBuffer":{"head":{"data":[123,34,105,115,85,115,101,114,83,117,98,115,99,114,105,98,101,100,34,58,116,114,117,101,44,34,115,101...]}

Comment: I don't know where exactly mistake but at least one I have found is you convert TO json instead of FROM. Here how it suppose to be String str = gson.fromJson("\"abc\"", String.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you convert TO json instead of FROM. Here how it suppose to be

```
String str = gson.fromJson("\"abc\"", String.class);
```